# Checkbox ALWAYS returns False/ not in request.POST - Django

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I have a checkbox on my django app, where user can add or remove a listing from their watchlist.

However, this checkbox always returns False, and is never in request.POST, i have tried sooo many solutions from SO and all over the internet for literal days now and cant figure it out

**Models.py**

```
class Watchlists(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='user')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    watchlist = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}, {self.user}, {self.watchlist}"
```

**Forms.py**

```
class CheckForm(ModelForm):
    watchlist = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    # watchlist = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={"value":"watchlist"}))
    class Meta:
        model = Watchlists
        fields = ['watchlist']
```

Checkbox didnt have a value so i thought that was the issue and tried to give it one here on the commented line, it didnt help

**Views.py**

```
        watchlist = CheckForm(request.POST or None)
          if request.method == 'POST':
            # if request.POST['watchlist']:
            # if 'watchlist' in request.POST:
            # if request.POST.get('watchlist', False):
            if request.POST.get('watchlist', '') == 'on':
                if watchlist.is_valid():
                    check = watchlist.cleaned_data['watchlist']
                    watchlist_data = Watchlists.objects.all().filter(title=title, user=username).first()
    
                    if not watchlist_data:
                        watchlisted = Watchlists.objects.create(title=title, user=username, watchlist='True')
                        watchlisted.save()
                    if watchlist_data:
                        watchlist_data.delete()

I have tried all the different solutions i could find

**Template**

                <form action="listing" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ checkbox }}
                </form>

It has a name and id attribute, label is fine too

**Entire views.py**

@login_required
def listing(request, title):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.get_username()

    form = BidForm()
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    watchlist = CheckForm(request.POST or None)

    listing_object = Listing.objects.all().filter(title=title).first()
    author = listing_object.user
    
    bids = Bid.objects.all().filter(title=title).values_list("price", flat=True)
    max_bid = max(bids, default=0)
    comments = Comment.objects.all().filter(list_title=title)
    

    if request.method == "POST":
        bid = Bid(title=title, user=username)
        bidform = BidForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=bid)
        
        # if request.POST['watchlist']:
        # if 'watchlist' in request.POST:
        # if request.POST.get('watchlist', False):
        if request.POST.get('watchlist', '') == 'on':
            if watchlist.is_valid():
                check = watchlist.cleaned_data['watchlist']
                watchlist_data = Watchlists.objects.all().filter(title=title, user=username).first()

                if not watchlist_data:
                    watchlisted = Watchlists.objects.create(title=title, user=username, watchlist='True')
                    watchlisted.save()
                if watchlist_data:
                    watchlist_data.delete()


        if "price" in request.POST:
            if bidform.is_valid():
                price = bid.price
                if not bids:
                    bid = bidform.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Your bid has been placed succesfully')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listing', args=(), kwargs={'title': title}))
                    
                else:
                    max_bid = max(bids)
                    if price >= listing_object.price and price > max_bid:
                        bid = bidform.save()
                        messages.success(request, 'Your bid has been placed succesfully')
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listing', args=(), kwargs={'title': title}))
                        
                    else:
                        messages.warning(request, 'Bid price must be greater than highest bid and starting price')
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listing', args=(), kwargs={'title': title}))
                        
            
        if "close" in request.POST:
            bid = Bid.objects.all().filter(title=title, price=max_bid).first()
            max_bid_user = bid.user

            listing_object.tag = 'closed'
            listing_object.save()

            if username == max_bid_user:
                messages.warning(request, 'Thank you for your entry into this auction. You have emerged the winner and this listing has been closed')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listing', args=(), kwargs={'title': title}))
                


        comment = Comment(user_commented=username, list_title=title, list_author=author)
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=comment)
        if "comment" in request.POST:
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                user_comment = comment_form.save()
                comments = Comment.objects.all().filter(list_title=title)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listing', args=(), kwargs={'title': title}))
                

    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "form": form,
        "listing": listing_object,
        "checkbox": watchlist,
        "max_bid": max_bid,
        "users": author,
        "commentform": comment_form,
        "comments": comments

    })
```

**urls.py**

```
path("auctions/<str:title>/", views.listing, name="listing"),
```

Comment: Share your entire view instead of only POST method and also share relevant urls.

Comment: `action` attribute must contain some url like `action="{% url 'listing' %}"` not only `listing`

Comment: its somewaht long but i have posted it

Comment: Anyway, I'd check it later when I'm free.

Comment: Okay, I can wait

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to add `blank=False` in your `watchlist` field since you gave it a default value, so rewrite it like so

```py
watchlist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

By doing so, you can also **remove** this from your **forms.py**. It's not necessary

```py
watchlist = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Just use as follows

```py
class CheckForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Watchlists
        fields = ['watchlist']
```

###### Additional things to fix based on [@Sunderam Dubey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17562044/sunderam-dubey)'s comment

In your HTML form, change `action="listing"` to `action="{% url 'listing' %}"`

Comment: I think you mean `blank=False` ? Also we can't say anything since action attribute of html form should also be something like `action="{% url 'listing' %}"` not only `listing` in action.

Comment: "I think you mean `blank=False`" Yes, I edited my answer.

Comment: @SunderamDubey Did all the above but the error still persists, although the listing path requires a title so what i did was more like `"{% url 'listing' listing.title %}`, could that be a possible issue to?